# AngularJS. Default child state with named views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI Router for my application. Their [FAQ page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state) covers default child state question, but they are not using named views and i can't figure out how to get this working.

Here are samples of my code:

index.html

```
<a ui-sref="/">Home</a>
<a ui-sref="topic.basics">Basics</a>
<a ui-sref="topic.payments">Payments</a>

<div ui-view="container" class="container"></div>
```

app.js

```
$stateProvider
  .state("/", {
    url: "/"
  })
  .state("topic", {
    url: "/topic/",
    abstract: true,
    // ?
  })
  .state("topic.basics", {
    url: "basics/",
    views: {
      "container": {
        templateUrl: "views/basics.html" 
      }
    }
  })
  .state("topic.payments", {
    url: "payments/",
    views: {
      "container": {
        templateUrl: "views/payments.html" 
      }
    }
  });

$urlRouterProvider
  .when("/topic/", "/topic/basics/")
  .otherwise("/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, but because the view target is not a parent, but index.html, we have to use aboslute naming

```
  .state("topic.basics", {
    url: "basics/",
    views: {
      // instead of this, which targets the parent
      // "container": {
      // we need this, where string empty after @ means root/index.html
      "container@": {
        templateUrl: "views/basics.html" 
      }
    }
  })
  .state("topic.payments", {
    url: "payments/",
    views: {
      // "container": {
      "container@": {
        templateUrl: "views/payments.html" 
      }
```

See

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.
>
> For example, the previous example could also be written as:

```
.state('report',{
    views: {
      'filters@': { },
      'tabledata@': { },
      'graph@': { }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the base home state abstract and remove the / in front of the /topic you already use this in the base route.

```
$stateProvider
  .state("home", {
    name: 'home',
    abstract: true,
    url: "/"
  })
  .state("topic", {
    name: 'home.topic',
    url: "topic/"
  })
  .state("topic.basics", {
    url: "basics/",
    name: 'home.topic.basics'
    views: {
      "container": {
        templateUrl: "views/basics.html" 
      }
    }
  })
  .state("topic.payments", {
    url: "payments/",
    name: 'home.topic.payments',
    views: {
      "container": {
        templateUrl: "views/payments.html" 
      }
    }
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```